# Jasmine + AngularJS + Chutzpah + getting unknown error

Tags: angularjs, typescript, jasmine, chutzpah

I am facing the issue while compiling the jasmine js unit test project

Please check following screen shot.

Previously i was getting the timeout issue but now i am getting "unknown error" issue.

Any one know the solution ?

[image]

Also some times i am getting following error

[image]

any pointer where to concentrate?

Comment: Could you provide a repro that I can execute locally and produce the same error?

Comment: Sometimes i am getting "phantom.exe-Application Error" The memory could not be written